# Wordpress get new post permalink title

Tags: wordpress

So I want to get the permalink title of a new published post.
example "http://myblog.com/healthy-life.php" I need healthy-life.php

here is code I have but it gets me http://myblog.com/healthy-life.php

```
function get_laterst_post_url() {
  global $wpdb;
  $query = "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_type='post' AND post_status='publish' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 1;";
  $result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
  if(is_object($result[0])) {
    return get_permalink($result[0]->ID);
  } else {
    return '';
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add:

```
$url = get_bloginfo('wpurl') . "/";
$permalink_title = str_replace($url, "", get_permalink($result[0]->ID));
return $permalink_title;
```

But its always best to use wordpress functions to get links. Say:

```
function get_laterst_post_url() {

$args = array(
'numberposts' => 1,
'orderby' => 'post_date',
'order' => 'DESC',
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => true );

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts();

$url = get_bloginfo('wpurl') . "/";
$permalink_title = str_replace($url, "", get_permalink($recent_posts[0]["ID"]));
return $permalink_title;
}
```

Comment: Yeah basically its:    $url = get_laterst_post_url();

Comment: hmm it's just weird I'm trying to transfer the permalink_title to my other .php that can do some work with it `$perma = get_laterst_post_url();
$url = "http://myblog.com/paste2.php?sub=" .$perma;
wp_remote_get( $url, $args = array() ); ` but I get it as full html not only the title any idea?

Comment: Yeah sorry I missed the $ of url, I think i need some sleep, it will work now :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [PHP's explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split at the slash and grab the last chunk of the array.

```php
// get the full URL, removing a trailing slash if it has one
$permalink = rtrim(get_permalink($result[0]->ID), "/");

// break that full URL into an array of the strings between each slash
$segments = explode("/", $permalink);

// get the last item in that array of segments
return array_pop($segments);
```

Credit to @Leander for the trailing slash adjustment, and the intervening nine years to comment my examples.

Comment: If the permalink (like in my case) ends with a slash ('/') then the `$permalink` will be assigned an empty string... So one should check for the permalink settings / output and trim accordingly, f.ex. via `substr(get_permalink($result[0]->ID), 0, -1);`

Comment: Good point, thanks @Leander! I updated my answer and used the slightly less terse [`rtrim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) to strip any trailing slash.

Comment: *More* terse. Slightly more terse. (Sigh.)